# CarrierWave: Use of file name in store_dir

Tags: ruby, carrierwave

I'm saving images to S3 using CarrierWave. Before uploading the images are renamed to a random string. Now for faster lookups I wanted to put the files in directories named after the two first letters of the filenames. But doing so, Rails aborts with `stack level too deep`.

So I assume calling `#{model.image[0, 2]` leads to an infinite recursion. Is there a way to access just the file name as a string? Or an even simpler solution?

This is the uploader:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "images/#{model.image[0, 2]}/"
  end

  def filename
    "#{secure_token}.#{file.extension}" if original_filename.present?
  end

  protected
  def secure_token
    var = :"@#{mounted_as}_secure_token"
    model.instance_variable_get(var) or model.instance_variable_set(var, SecureRandom.hex(8))
  end

end
```

Comment: try to use model.image.identifier

Comment: Thanks, but same result. I think the reference to model.image or model.image.identifier triggers store_dir again, but maybe I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try the `:file_identifier` method

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  ...

  def store_dir
    "images/#{model.file_identifier[0, 2]}/#{model.id}"
  end

  ...

end
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer is to add a proxy attribute such as `filename` in the `Image` model and access that using `read_attribute`:

```
class Image < ApplicationRecord
  mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader

  def filename
    read_attribute(:image)
  end
  ...
end
```

Then in your `ImageUploader#store_dir method` make reference to the proxy attribute `filename`:

```
  def store_dir
    "images/#{model.filename}"
  end
```

This worked for me and eliminated the recursive error problem.